# Vertical navbar of arbitrary width fixed left. How do I pad the main content?

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical navbar on the left side of the screen. It's height is 100% of the viewport. It's fixed. Its **width is arbitrary**.

How do I shift the content beneath it so it doesn't cover it up?

Here's an illustration of my problem:

```css
.sideNav {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
}

.content {}
```

```html
<div class="sideNav">
  <ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Long Item Number Three</li>
    <li>Another Item of arbitrary length</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, liber feugait dolores mei id, per epicurei inimicus definiebas ne. Ne sumo equidem eam, no sit detracto constituto. Case graece offendit eum at, simul ullamcorper ne mel, fugit interesset cotidieque est no. Ius rebum iriure
    labitur ex. Eu sit atomorum tractatos, per liber officiis oportere eu, ea per perfecto repudiandae.</p>

  <p>Duo virtute voluptua ea. Scribentur instructior est ea, at cum eruditi pericula interesset. Impetus molestie intellegam usu no, has errem choro detracto ei. Has augue dicunt at, eos ei verear tamquam adipiscing. Eu ponderum consetetur nec. Consul scripta
    principes id eam.</p>

  <p>Eam illum facer sententiae at. Cum insolens constituto sadipscing ad, et eum ubique fuisset. Possit torquatos at mel. In diam mediocrem sea. Te hinc phaedrum has. Dolorum veritus appetere mei at.</p>

  <p>Has id docendi reprehendunt, numquam fuisset eu per. Has cu ubique insolens, te ius consul aperiam iudicabit. Electram efficiantur ut duo. No delectus maluisset liberavisse qui, ius et corpora repudiare. Est iuvaret corpora pertinacia te, mel eripuit
    appetere prodesset in, eos ei omnis salutatus.</p>

  <p>Mea cu choro option facilis, mei eu mutat laoreet eleifend. Sit oratio nullam doming ad, ut vix mucius aliquip, ut quot appetere pri. Ius ad ullum gloriatur, id putent mentitum eum, ne vero harum vix. Has ne vocibus expetenda. Mea sumo eros forensibus
    et, velit constituam his cu.</p>

  <p>Malis tincidunt ex ius, vis blandit mandamus ei. Veri tation praesent pri ut, ea pro habemus ponderum prodesset. Ex nam ubique maiestatis. Debet doming usu cu.</p>

  <p>Eum ad mutat probatus, no per mucius evertitur signiferumque, augue novum ut sed. Ad his omnium cetero, insolens deterruisset ei per, no clita tincidunt efficiantur mea. Quo tota feugiat et. Ex ipsum fabulas mea, cu sed consul nominavi salutatus. Fabulas
    fastidii disputando ut per, nibh suavitate sea no. Ex doming ceteros mei, mei in exerci dolores.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: You can use padding-left to adjust your content to navbar, but as I suppose you're looking for an automated solution.

Comment: What determines the width of the navbar, its content?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the `.sideNav`'s width on page load and apply the same as `.content`'s `padding-left` with some more, like so

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var sideNavWidth = document.querySelector('.sideNav').clientWidth;
  var content = document.querySelector('.content');

  content.style.paddingLeft = sideNavWidth + 10 + 'px';
});
```

```css
.sideNav {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.content {}
```

```html
<div class="sideNav">
  <ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Long Item Number Three</li>
    <li>Another Item of arbitrary length</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, liber feugait dolores mei id, per epicurei inimicus definiebas ne. Ne sumo equidem eam, no sit detracto constituto. Case graece offendit eum at, simul ullamcorper ne mel, fugit interesset cotidieque est no. Ius rebum iriure
    labitur ex. Eu sit atomorum tractatos, per liber officiis oportere eu, ea per perfecto repudiandae.</p>

  <p>Duo virtute voluptua ea. Scribentur instructior est ea, at cum eruditi pericula interesset. Impetus molestie intellegam usu no, has errem choro detracto ei. Has augue dicunt at, eos ei verear tamquam adipiscing. Eu ponderum consetetur nec. Consul scripta
    principes id eam.</p>

  <p>Eam illum facer sententiae at. Cum insolens constituto sadipscing ad, et eum ubique fuisset. Possit torquatos at mel. In diam mediocrem sea. Te hinc phaedrum has. Dolorum veritus appetere mei at.</p>

  <p>Has id docendi reprehendunt, numquam fuisset eu per. Has cu ubique insolens, te ius consul aperiam iudicabit. Electram efficiantur ut duo. No delectus maluisset liberavisse qui, ius et corpora repudiare. Est iuvaret corpora pertinacia te, mel eripuit
    appetere prodesset in, eos ei omnis salutatus.</p>

  <p>Mea cu choro option facilis, mei eu mutat laoreet eleifend. Sit oratio nullam doming ad, ut vix mucius aliquip, ut quot appetere pri. Ius ad ullum gloriatur, id putent mentitum eum, ne vero harum vix. Has ne vocibus expetenda. Mea sumo eros forensibus
    et, velit constituam his cu.</p>

  <p>Malis tincidunt ex ius, vis blandit mandamus ei. Veri tation praesent pri ut, ea pro habemus ponderum prodesset. Ex nam ubique maiestatis. Debet doming usu cu.</p>

  <p>Eum ad mutat probatus, no per mucius evertitur signiferumque, augue novum ut sed. Ad his omnium cetero, insolens deterruisset ei per, no clita tincidunt efficiantur mea. Quo tota feugiat et. Ex ipsum fabulas mea, cu sed consul nominavi salutatus. Fabulas
    fastidii disputando ut per, nibh suavitate sea no. Ex doming ceteros mei, mei in exerci dolores.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I could use Javascript, but I'd like to do it without Javascript if at all possible. There *must* be a way to do it.

I think for a temporary fix I'm going to add 2 copies of the navbar into the HTML on top of each other. One will provide the spacing and one will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the `sideNav` and `content` elements into a container div and use flex positioning like so:

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="sideNav">
    <ul>
      <li>Item One</li>
      <li>Item Two</li>
      <li>Long Item Number Three</li>
      <li>Another Item of arbitrary length</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, liber feugait dolores mei id, per epicurei inimicus definiebas ne. Ne sumo equidem eam, no sit detracto constituto. Case graece offendit eum at, simul ullamcorper ne mel, fugit interesset cotidieque est no. Ius rebum iriure
      labitur ex. Eu sit atomorum tractatos, per liber officiis oportere eu, ea per perfecto repudiandae.</p>

    <p>Duo virtute voluptua ea. Scribentur instructior est ea, at cum eruditi pericula interesset. Impetus molestie intellegam usu no, has errem choro detracto ei. Has augue dicunt at, eos ei verear tamquam adipiscing. Eu ponderum consetetur nec. Consul
      scripta principes id eam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.site-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sideNav {
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.content{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

The `sideNav` has a `max-width` for larger screens.